# Best Practice - Redirect to Third Party URL with JWT

Tags: c#, api, security, jwt

I have a web interface that takes a user from a third party website. The user performs some actions and then is to be redirected back to the third party website. I want to provide a JWT to the third party website to include some information about the user, and confirm that it was my interface that sent the customer back. I'm trying to understand what is considered best practise.

- GET redirect. Should I perform a redirect and include the JWT in the URL as a parameter? I gather the downside is I may have issues with the size of the JWT in the URL, and the user may try submitting the URL again. I understand I can't include the JWT in the header for a GET redirect.
- POST with the JWT in the header. I gather I might have issues with CORS in posting to a third party domain.
- POST with the JWT in a cookie.

I don't want to send the third party website an authentication code that they need to use to get confirmation from my API. I just want them to be able to confirm the redirect is coming from my system.

Comment: Please read [Is a "best practice" question off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/265928/edit) and the related duplicate, and then come back and restate your question.

Comment: FYI @KenWhite the link says "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue. Try again in a few minutes.". I don't know if you meant to link to a /edit.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265928/62576